# Lumen + Angular error 500 when get multiple requests from API

Tags: php, angular, jwt, lumen

I've problem with loading requests from API - they load sometimes and sometimes not (occurred 500 - internal server error).

Basically occures two errors:

> GET http://localhost:4200/api/warehouse/largest-amount 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> ERROR Argument 3 passed to
>   Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac::doVerify() must be an instance of
>   Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key, null given, called in
>   C:\laragon\www\store\vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Signer\BaseSigner.php
>   on line 44

and much less often just

> GET http://localhost:4200/api/warehouse/largest-amount 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> ERROR Server Error

I've tested every single request multiple times by postman and there wasn't any errors - it's look like they occure just when they are all loading in the same time (e.g refreshing site?). There is no pattern for those errors, sometimes it jump out on first request and other time in last.

Here is my web.php

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {

    $router->get('warehouse',  ['uses' => 'WarehousesController@showAll']);
    $router->get('warehouse/largest-amount',  ['uses' => 'WarehousesController@getLargestAmount']);


    $router->get('sale',  ['uses' => 'SalesController@showAll']);
    $router->get('sale/month-profit',  ['uses' => 'SalesController@showMonthProfit']);
    $router->get('sale/year-profit',  ['uses' => 'SalesController@showYearProfit']);
    $router->get('sale/chart-data-sale',  ['uses' => 'SalesController@chartDataSale']);
    $router->get('sale/chart-data-cost-items',  ['uses' => 'SalesController@chartDataCostItems']);
    $router->get('sale/char-data-profit',  ['uses' => 'SalesController@chartDataProfit']);


    $router->get('payment',  ['uses' => 'PaymentsController@showAll']);
    $router->get('payment/{day}_{year}', ['uses' => 'PaymentsController@showOne']);
    $router->get('payment/overdue', ['uses' => 'PaymentsController@showOverdue']);
    $router->get('payment/overdue-end', ['uses' => 'PaymentsController@showOverdueEnd']);

    $router->get('profile', ['uses' => 'AuthController@getUser']);
});
```

and here is example of angular

```
  getSaleMonthProfit(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`/sale/month-profit`)
  }
```

I thought it has something to do with this middleware (that's why i put this code above), but i don't really know anymore

Comment: Is your HMAC verification being passed correctly from Angular? I assume you had that set up in Postman

Comment: @benJ I don't know, how can i check it?

Comment: @crane
Your must send a request token in the headers.

Comment: ah, ofc everything is in pleace - like: "Authorization: Bearer..."